# Remove everything but certain HTML tags in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm working with some HTML in PHP, whenever I try using a HTML/XML parser, it returns absurdly large and complex objects/arrays. Sometimes it doesn't even do that because the HTML I'm working with is sometimes occasionally misformatted in some places, but it's misformatted in places that aren't important to me. Because of this, I've just decided to use some string functions on the code and it's going great.

All that aside, here's what I need. This is my HTML:

```
<section id="whatever">
  <article>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>Another itle</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
  </article>
</section>
```

I want to remove everything that isn't a `p` tag, so I want the final value to be something like this:

```
<p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
```

The data can be returned in any way, I don't need the attributes on the element or anything like that, I just need the contents of the tag.

Comment: If you want to extract all paragraphs (but strip everything that isn't within a p tag), you will require using a parser. Before recommending anything, I must ask first, what parsers have you tried?

Comment: I have another doubt: Considering <p>Hola <p>wadup <div>sooo</div></p></p>, would you want the <div>sooo</div> to disappear or would that be alright since it is inside of a <p>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [preg_match_all()](http://www.php.net/preg_match_all):

```
$html = '<section id="whatever">
  <article>
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
  </article>
  <article>
    <h1>Another itle</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
  </article>
</section>';

preg_match_all ('/<p.*?>(.*?)<\/p>/', $html, $result);

print_r ($result[0]);

/*
Array
(
    [0] => <p>The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.</p>
    [1] => <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adipiscing elit.</p>
)
*/
```

Comment: HTML is not parsable with regular expressions since its grammar is free of context. Your regex would fail the moment you have complex paragraphs.

Comment: Worked perfectly, results in an array and everything, better than I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Mamsaac That is true. However, for the purpose of the OP's problem, using regex would be sufficient since OP is only worried about getting whatever is between the paragraph tags. And of course, you can't have `<p>` inside `<p>` since that's invalid HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use [`strip_tags`](https://www.php.net/strip_tags)

```
echo strip_tags($str, '<p>');
```

Comment: Because the OP doesn't want to just strip out the HTML, but rather to get rid of everything outside the paragraphs, including the heading text.